# Find a dimension and basis of W as a subspace of the vector space $\Bbb P^3$ where $W = \{c + cx^2 + dx^3 \mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a dimension and basis of $W$ as a subspace of the vector space $\Bbb P^3$ where $W = \{c + cx^2 + dx^3 \mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$.

I need some guidance. My textbook generally asks for basis and dimension and gives you a set of vectors, so I've never seen a question phrased this way. Any help in layman's terms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $W$ *is* a set of vectors. It just so happens that the vectors (elements) in $P_3$ are polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g\in P_3$ be
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= 1+t^2 & g(t)=t^3
\end{align*}
and note that $W=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{f,g\}$.

To show that $\{f,g\}$ are linearly independent, suppose that
$$
\lambda_1f+\lambda_2g=\vec 0\tag{1}
$$
Note that (1) is equivalent to 
$$
\lambda_1f(t)+\lambda_2g(t)=0\quad\forall t\in\Bbb R\tag{2}
$$
Taking $t=0,1$ in (2) gives
\begin{array}{rcrcr}
\lambda_1    & &           &=& 0 \\
2\,\lambda_1 &+& \lambda_2 &=& 0
\end{array}
It follows that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$ so that $\{f,g\}$ is linearly independent. Hence $\{f,g\}$ is a basis for $W$. In particular, $\dim W=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if $p(x)\in W$ then $$p(x)=c+cx^2+dx^3=c(1+x^2)+d(x^3),$$ so $W=\operatorname{Span}\{1+x^2, x^3\}$, where this two generators vectors form a basis for $W$. Therefore $\operatorname{dim} W= 2$.